# C# SMTP sent from server not on the same domain as Exchange is blank

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email, smtp, exchange-server

I've just written a piece of code for a MVC website that sends a SMTP email using the .NET `SmtpClient` via our Exchange server. The email it sends has a HTML body with links to images and a file that are hosted on the website.

The email is sent fine when run internally on our network, but when its run from the hosted server that's not on our domin, the email comes through but the body is blank. Does anybody have any idea why? Is is because of the linked images or file that could be a potential threat and come from a server not on the domain and so is not trusted?

Here's the code that sends the email, it uses the `MailDefinition` class to insert a link to a file into the body that they've requested to download:

```
MailDefinition md = new MailDefinition();
md.From = "test@testing.com";
md.Subject = "Test Email";
md.IsBodyHtml = true;

ListDictionary replacements = new ListDictionary();
replacements.Add("REQUESTED_LINK", @"C:\MyFile.pdf");

MailMessage email = md.CreateMailMessage(mailTo, replacements, content, new System.Web.UI.Control());

SmtpClient emailClient = new SmtpClient();
emailClient.Host = "MyExchangeServer";

emailClient.Send(email);
```

Comment: Is the body truly empty or is the HTML not rendered by your client? What client did you use to check this? Can you save the message to a file and check what's in the body? You should probably add some plain text description in your message anyway to account for such cases.

Comment: It appears to be truly empty. I've tested this with exchange 2010, saved the email as plain text, opened it up and its got sections for the From, To, Sent Date and Subject but no Body. I've also sent it to my Hotmail account and it appears blank there too, although I'm not sure how to test it any further from there.

Comment: Can you even send pure HTML messages? Perhaps your hoster is blocking event those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed, turns out the .html file containing the body of the email hadn't been deployed to the live server, and so the body of the email was blank as a result. Adding it fixed the problem, so it turns out it wasn't a security issue after all. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

My guess is Value for [`MailDefinition.BodyFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.maildefinition.bodyfilename.aspx) missing from the code.

*The name of the file that contains the message body text. The default is Empty.*

On development or in internal sevrer `BodyFileName` has a some value. On hosted sevrer file is missing so email Body is empty.

see this [Example for reference](http://jesal.us/2008/10/send-templated-emails-using-maildefinition-object/)

Comment: Close, the body of the email was being passed though in the 'content' parameter, but it turns out the file containing the email body hadn't been deployed, and so 'content' was empty